# efficiently find element in array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, search

I have this very long array of objects:

```
public static class __Location {
    public __Location(int locationId, String locationDesc) {
        this.LocationId = locationId;
        this.LocationDesc = locationDesc;
    }

    public int LocationId;
    public String LocationDesc;
}


public static __Location[] LOCATIONS = { new __Location(100, "Afghanistan"), new __Location(110, "Albania"), new __Location(120, "Algeria"),
        new __Location(130, "American Samoa"), new __Location(140, "Andorra"), new __Location(150, "Angola"), new __Location(160, "Anguilla"),
        new __Location(170, "Antarctica"), new __Location(180, "Antigua And Barbuda"), new __Location(190, "Argentina"), new __Location(200, "Armenia"),
        new __Location(210, "Aruba"), new __Location(220, "Australia"), new __Location(230, "Austria"), new __Location(240, "Azerbaijan"),
        new __Location(250, "Bahamas"), new __Location(260, "Bahrain"), new __Location(270, "Bangladesh"), new __Location(280, "Barbados"),
        new __Location(290, "Belarus"), new __Location(300, "Belgium"), new __Location(310, "Belize"), new __Location(320, "Benin"),
        new __Location(330, "Bermuda"), new __Location(340, "Bhutan"), new __Location(350, "Bolivia"), new __Location(360, "Bosnia And Herzegovina"),
        new __Location(370, "Botswana"), new __Location(380, "Bouvet Island"), new __Location(390, "Brazil"),
        new __Location(400, "British Indian Ocean Territory"), ...
```

My question is how can I efficiently search for an item in this long array (according to its key value, i.e., LocationId).

Comment: If the array is sorted, you can use binary search.

Comment: Is `locationId` unique?

Comment: If all locations in your array are unique, you should consider implementing `.equals()`/`.hashCode()` and using a `HashSet`.

Comment: @Solace good point, however this requires `__Location` to implement `Comparable<__Location>`, or use a `Comparator<__Location>`

Comment: Are all location ID's multiples of 10? How many are there total? You may be able to simply initialize an array at compile-time with the index of each entry being equal to the location ID divided by 10. Any missing elements in your array initializer can be set to `null`. This may be impractical if the number of elements is large and the location ID's are sparse, but your code fragments seems to indicate that is not a problem. With little effort this scheme can be extended for location ID's which are not all divisible by 10, but a `HashMap` might then be the better choice of implementation.

Comment: All locationId's are unique and currently a multiply of 10, however, I wouldn't want to establish my search on this fact because in the future I might add objects in between other objects which will not have a multiply of 10 id.

Comment: Please use [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) - classes should be named in `PascalCase`. `__Location` should be `Location`.

Comment: @fge Performing a binary search on an array of objects does not require an object to implement `Comparable<__Location>` or any other interface unless the implementation of binary search you use requires it. The same is true is you will use a `HashMap` implementation without the requirement to implement `.equals/.hashCode` on the objects in the a collection. In fact, `hashCode` is one of the great warts on the Java object system and should avoided.

Comment: @NedNowotny uhm, read the javadoc of `Arrays.binarySearch()` again... As to `HashSet`, it requires elements to comply to the equals/hashCode contract.

Comment: @user739809 Then use a `HashMap` unless there is a clear need for faster setup and lookup times. In that case, statically initialize an array of integers where each index will be an index into your location  ID array of the first element with a location ID in the range from the location ID computed by multiplying the index used in the lookup array by 10 up to the next location ID divisible by 10. That, of course, will still require the location object array to be sorted by location ID. The implementation is very simple to code correctly and is completely initialized at compile-time.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Most non-trivial objects cannot implement a hash code which is appropriate for all hash collections into which the objects may be inserted. The indexing and lookup of objects is a responsibility best left to the collection, not the elements in a collection aside, perhaps, from the wrapper objects for primitives which seems to have inspired the `hashCode` wart on `Object.` For more, see the footnote on this question: [Implementing a Number System in Java: Mutable vs. Immutable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573242/implementing-a-number-system-in-java-mutable-vs-immutable)

Comment: @NedNowotny a valid point; although I don't agree with it. In any case this isn't the place for such discussions.

Comment: @fge Binary search is a trivial algorithm provided by a number of sources if you do not wish to write one of your own. The requirement for an object to implement the `Comparable` interface is an unnecessary complication injected into the common solution of a simple problem. However, it is well within the Java tradition of adding verbose complexity where it is unneeded which is then used by language critics to wrongly assert that strong static type-checking is the problem easily "supported" with widely available Java code fragments.

Comment: @BoristheSpider With hash tables or hash maps being a proposed solution to this problem, it is entirely appropriate and on topic to recommend against using hash collections which require implementation of `hashCode` on classes whose instances will be added to hashed collections. Sticking with the the standard collection classes is more than reasonable, but `HashMap` should always be prefered over `HashSet` or other collection classes dependent on `hashCode` with the obvious exception of "immutable" instances of the primitive value wrapper classes.

Comment: @NedNowotny I don't understand how `HashMap` is any different to `HashSet`. A `HashSet` _is a_ `HashMap`.

Comment: @NedNowotny "The requirement for an object to implement the Comparable interface is an unnecessary complication injected into the common solution of a simple problem." <-- right, so, tell me if there is any natural ordering to the OP's `__Location` as it is currently defined...

Comment: @BoristheSpider A `HashSet` requires the implementation of `.equals/.hashCode` on the objects inserted into it. A `HashMap` only requires implementation of `.equals/.hashCode` on the keys which may be either immutable wrappers for primitive values or instances of an immutable special purpose class appropriate for the specific application and hidden away in the implementation so the practical necessity of immutable keys is not subverted by a user of the code.

Comment: @fge Because `locationId` is an `int`, I believe you have the answer to your question. In the unlikely case where multiple `__Location` objects may have the same `locationId,` then the question is whether hashing and look up must then compare descriptions or should the collection return a list or set for all `__Loaction` objects which share the same `locationId` value? Again, that is dependent on the application and the collection used to implement it. Foisting one implementation of `Comparable` on the `Location` class is not particularly helpful.

Comment: @NedNowotny you seem to miss the fact that there is no "magic generated" `Comparable` implementation in Java...

Comment: @fge I would leave it. The suggestion seems to be to implement binary search oneself rather than using the JDK impl. This discussion is getting a little silly.

Comment: There are many Java implementations of binary search widely available if you do not want to write or test your own. If the only implementation you can find in the JDK will only work on arrays of objects -- i.e. no arrays of say `int`, `char`, or `double` -- and only if they implement `Comparable`, then look elsewhere unless you really want the implementation details of a collection injecting itself into the classes you write.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I agree, not only silly but pointless... Some fundamental Java API concepts seem to be completely forgotten here

Comment: But not to worry, the Java [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) does offer all the binary search you need without `Comaparable`.

Comment: But are "fundamental Java API concepts" which require a developer to implement some interface to use a collection really "good" fundamental Java API concepts? Sometimes, perhaps, but most of the time it is better to select classes from the available and third-party APIs which do not require your classes to implement code irrelevant to the concept a given class is meant to implement.

Comment: But whether you agree with any of my other recommendations, at least adopt one convention, never implement `hashCode` or the `Comparable` interface on mutable objects so that you will never be tempted to index mutable objects in a collection when a later edit may change the state of an object without first removing and then adding it back to all relevant collections. Mutable keys, especially objects which are themselves the key, is a design defect waiting to become an implementation defect.

Comment: @NedNowotny your last comment is a **very** sound piece of advice. Objects should never be hashed or compared on mutable _properties_. So my only disagreement there would be that the properties need to be immutable rather than the whole object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: rename `__Location` to `Location`.

Second: you talk about "efficient search", fine. Now answer these two questions:

- where does this location you want to search for come from? Is it a result of a `new Location()`? The id of this location? The string of this location?
- in the container you want to lookup from, are the existing locations sorted? If yes, what against? The id? The string?

Without a clear answer to this question, it is impossible to answer your question.

Let us assume, since that is the most simple case, that a `Location` is identified by its `locationId`; you know that for a given `locationId`, the `locationString` will be unique.

For maximum efficiency, you should then implement the `.equals()`/`.hashCode()` contract in `Location` and use a `HashSet`:

```
public static class Location {
    private final int locationId;
    private final String locationDesc;

    public Location(final int locationId, final String locationDesc)
    {
        this.locationId = locationId;
        this.locationDesc = locationDesc;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return locationId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        final Location other = (Location) obj;
        return locationId == other.locationId;
    }
}
```

Then use a `HashSet<Location>` to insert `Location`s and use this `Set`'s `.contains()` method.

Comment: +1 for a comprehensive breakdown of the missing information. Think I would still prefer a `Map` here however.

Comment: But what would be the key?

Comment: I would say the `id` - just because this makes the intention of the code clear. It also allows lookup by id which a `Set` doesn't. The OP uses the word _search_ which gives me the impression that the OP wants to find a `Location` given an `id`.

Comment: Well, anoter solution would probably be to use Guava's `Equivalence<Location>` depending on the criterion ;)

Comment: First, don't implement `hashCode` and `equals` though the location class is reasonably considered "immutable" in the given code fragment. But if you must, at least implement your `hashCode` method as `new Integer( locationId ).hashCode()`. An integer value itself may not produce the best results. If you do not like creating and throwing away an `Integer`, then "steal" a reasonable integer hash function from an open source JDK implementation or any of a number of other third-party implementations. Failing that, instrument your code and tune your `hashCode` to achieve a good hash distribution.

Comment: @NedNowotny none of your remarks make sense; if you really want the fine points of it, look at `HashMap`'s implementation.

Comment: I guess @NedNowotny has a small point in that using the `id` directly might result in clustering of values (between `1` and `numLocations` for example) - you probably want multiply by a large prime to "scatter" the hashes as evenly as possible across the `int` space.

Comment: @NedNowotny I think you're partly right (although the answer hardly deserves a down-vote) but you're wrong in your suggestions to fix. The JDK just [returns `value` from the `hashCode` function for `Integer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.hashCode%28%29).

Comment: Or, if you are averse to straying beyond the JDK, simply use `return new Integer( locationId ).hashCode();` to implement the `hashCode` method which will likely ensure a "better" result which is also consistent with the old -- and now, very outdated -- adage that, "no one ever got fired for choosing IBM."

Comment: @BoristheSpider You are absolutely correct. Thank you for the pointer. Might as well save the allocation of an `Integer` and a method call. Probably best to not rely on the compiler, static or JIT, to optimize away all unnecessary overhead. Later profiling, should performance ever rise to a level for concern (unlikely), may reveal it is worthwhile to divide the `locationId` by ten for this particular case. But barring the unexpected, I concede that simply returning the `int` value is sufficient.

Comment: I also agree the "down-vote" is really unjustified and will reverse it. Though, I cast it for adding twenty lines to the implementation of the location class for indexing and lookup in one proposed collection and for having that code implement the more than slightly problematic `hashCode` method the Java language developers imply should be part of the "contract" for every object, but not primitive values...except the reference to objects by default... Regardless, I will eliminate the "down-vote" as long as at least a trivial edit is made to the answer to enable me to do so.

Comment: @fge If you use `HashMap` instead of `HashSet`, the code in your answer is unnecessary. Just create a `HashMap`, and `map.put( location.locationId, location )`. Java will "autobox the `locationId` into an `Integer` for you. Then simply look up location objects using values expected to map to valid `locationId` values. Again, without any of the twenty lines of code you wrote for `hashCode` and `equals`. Is arguing against writing and testing unnecessary code simply a "fine point?"

Comment: Well, the OP doesn't say what he wants, so I went to a `HashSet` by default. Barring more details, this is the solution I came up with.

Comment: O.K. But using `HashSet` instead of `HashMap` requires the additional code you provided just to get the same functionality. Your answer is not "wrong" -- and I will still correct my "down-vote" if I can, but Stack Overflow tells me an edit to the answer is now required -- but extra code means more code to test and all for no benefit. Even so, my real problem is not your answer, but my aversion to `hashCode` under almost any circumstance.

Comment: Uh... Well, if you implement `.equals()`, would you _really_ be averse to implementing `.hashCode()`? (nevermind the downvote here)

Comment: If you must implement `.equals()`, the Java language designers pretty much insist you implement `.hashCode()` as a stated in this quote from the API documentation for `Object`: "If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result." The default of simply returning the "reference" to the object meets the letter, but not the spirit of that requirement. Joshua Bloch  is far more explicit in his "Item 8: Always override hashCode when you override equals" in Effective Java. More warts...

Comment: If you model object systems on numbers, equality, relative value, and even hash codes are fairly well defined by the values your objects denote -- though rational numbers begin to challenge the notion of hash code while complex numbers introduce problems with defining a universal "order." And therein lies the problem with defining methods on objects which are intended for use by the possible collection to which they may be added. A collection, its indexing, if any, and the method by which objects are retrieved from it are traits of the collection, not its contents. Java presumes otherwise.

Comment: Hold on; there is a huge difference between `.equals()`/`.hashCode()` and `Comparable`. You can design classes which are `Comparable` but don't implement `.equals()`/`.hashCode()` or the reverse. This is why Java has `HashSet` and `TreeSet`. I really don't see your point at all.

Comment: By the way, my comment above about returning an object reference meeting, "the letter, but not the spirit of that requirement," is obviously correct only for classes whose every instance is unique. If two objects may be "equal," but distinct objects just the same, returning a reference is inadequate to fulfill the "contract." Hence, the trouble with tribb...`.hashCode()`...

Comment: My point is you can use JDK collection classes which do not require you to implement `.equals()/.hashCode()` or `Comparable` in your own classes designed to implement objects which model your application domain rather than dragging in extraneous and public details imposed by the designer of a collection class. Collections should manage themselves using methods implemented on extensions of themselves, if necessary, not by requiring code be injected into whatever they may be asked to contain. After all, if the OP first used binary search and later switched to a `HashSet`, consider the impact.

Comment: @fge Yes, I realize this should be a "discussion," but... You are, of course, correct that `IdentityHashSet` is an appropriate collection class for classes where every instance is unique. However, I am really more concerned by the "contract" which insists that `.hashCode()` must be implemented whenever `.equals()` is implemented for classes which cannot simply return a reference to satisfy the requirement. That becomes even more onerous when there is no intent to "hash" instances at all, but an `.equals()` method may still have utility. The contract requires `.hashCode()` "just in case."

Comment: (about the "discussion" stuff: this is an automatic SO feature, not my doing) The "just in case" matters a _lot_; if you implement equals() but forget to do hashCode(), a `List`'s .contains() would work but not a `HashSet` nor a `Map` if your class is used as a key; this is reason enough to pair the two, isn't it?

Comment: I agree completely that implementing ".equals()" in Java as designed requires you to implement `.hashCode`. But unless you are implementing a class for immutable objects with very simple, clear, and well understood semantics, I recommend not implementing either as methods. If you want to provide a test for equality without taking on `.hashCode`, implement a static method to check two objects for equality. That does seem unnecessary and would be if the "contract" were not what it is. `Object` and the Java "contract" it imposes adds an unnecessary and often overly complex burden.

Comment: Think of it this way: order, equality, and categorization -- i.e. binning or hashing -- are artifacts of taxonomy, not intrinsic characteristics of most objects you may ever need to model.

Comment: Well, this is why Guava has `Equivalence<T>`. The fact remains though that Java's `.equals()`/`.hashCode()` contract is consistent and satisfies 99+% use cases, so...

Comment: It is also a consistent cause of errors and poorly performing code when hashed collections degenerate into O(n) linear lookup. Perhaps not that often in practice, but still common. But consider an `Employee` class hashed and compared on an `Id` member. Any collection of `Employee` objects you need to create which enable lookup by division, location, job title, etc. will require collections which cannot rely on `Employee.hashCode` or on instances being `Comparable` even if equality is still meaningful as implemented. For many other domains, there is no easy choice like an `Id` for `hashCode()`.

Comment: Well, again, this is why Guava has `Equivalence` ;)

Comment: Thank you all so much for this discussion. I learned a lot. I should mention that I am an Android developer working against C# server, hence this peculiar __Location naming for the array. This array is indeed kept sorted and the search is performed on the locationId.

Answer (score 2):

With `HashMap` you can access the item efficiently, the time complexity is `O(1)`:

```
Map<Integer, __Location> map = new HashMap<Integer, __Location>();
```

The `key` of this `HashMap` is `LocationId`, the `value` is the corresponding `__Location object`.

Comment: That requires a bit of work to do that... Where does that `Integer` key come from, for instance?

Comment: @fge The `Integer` is the "autoboxed" location ID from the object. No real work at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you use keys, why don't you try using a map?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

That way, you can look up a value by it's key, from the context I assume that's what you want to do?

Comment: `Map` is an appropriate interface, but it still matters which implementation is used. For example, I strongly recommend `hashMap` with immutable keys over a `hashSet` of any class of objects other than the primitive value wrapper objects.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a HashSet

```
Set<_location> locationSet = new HashSet<_location>();
locationSet.add(new __Location(130, "American Samoa"));
...
_location searchLocation = //some _location instance;
if (locationSet.contains(searchLocation)) {
  //found it
}
```

You will need to override the hashcode and equals methods for your _location class such that equality is determined by locationID.

This is much more efficient then array search which requires traversal. You have O(1) search for HashSet vs O(n) for array

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _You have `O(1)` search for `HashSet` vs `O(n)` for array_. A `HashSet` has an `O(1)` `contains` method but this doesn't help with searching given an index. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I just assumed the OP wanted to search and evaluate whether a given _location was contained in the set. In reflection, if the OP is actually interested in retrieving the value locationDesc then a HashMap is the better implementation.